# How to target the css for inputfields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, inputfield, font

I have a lightning component where the fonts a returning white which makes it difficult to read. I read some solutions deinstalling a calendar or reinstalling chrome which did not work in my case so I want to solve this trough CSS.

With inspect I found working:

```
Inherited from div.slds-show
Style Attribute {
    color: rgb(5, 117, 216);
}
```

I tried

```
.THIS.slds-show {
    color: rgb(5, 117, 216);
}
```

This seems not to be working, how can I target this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who bumps into this, what I found working was:

```
.THIS .slds-show {
    color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: yes and if its topmost, then space is not needed, (as I mentioned in answer)

Comment: @ salesforce-sas Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If `slds-show` is direct child of component then this will work:

```
.THIS.slds-show {
    color: rgb(5, 117, 216);
}
```

If its not direct child and is located inside some other elements, then you need space:

```
.THIS .slds-show {
    color: rgb(5, 117, 216);
}
```

Comment: I tried both but they are not working, could this be because of the component beiing a child component.